# Stopwatch application is delayed and recursive

Tags: python, tkinter

In my code, whenever I press the start button again, it goes faster and you have to press stop multiple times. Along with this, it takes longer than a second to input another second any help would be nice. Thank you in advance! I am not entirely sure what I could do in this scenario, so some help would be greatly appreciated! As mentioned before, the time it takes to make one second on this app is slower than on a normal stopwatch, and I am not sure what I can do to fix this. Along with this, pressing the button again makes time go faster, and causes recursion, so I am not sure how to do this.

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import sys

#sys.setrecursionlimit(1)

hours = 0
minutes = 0
seconds = 0   
milliseconds = 0

window = Tk()
window.title("Stopwatch")
window.configure(width=500, height = 100)

time = StringVar()
time.set("00:00:00:00")

is_stop = False

def plus_sec():
    global hours
    global minutes
    global seconds
    global milliseconds

    milliseconds += 1
    if milliseconds == 100:
        milliseconds = 0
        seconds += 1
    if seconds == 60:
        seconds = 0
        minutes += 1
    if minutes == 60:
        minutes = 0
        hours += 1

    h_s = str(hours)
    min_s = str(minutes)
    sec_s = str(seconds)
    mil_s = str(milliseconds)

    if len(h_s) < 2:
        h_s = '0' + h_s
    if len(min_s) < 2:
        min_s = '0' + min_s
    if len(sec_s) < 2:
        sec_s = '0' + sec_s
    if len(mil_s) < 2:
        mil_s = '0' + mil_s

    time.set(h_s + ":" + min_s + ":" + sec_s + ":" + mil_s)

def begin():
    global is_stop
    if is_stop == False:
        plus_sec()
        window.after(10, begin)
        window.update()
    else:
        pass
        is_stop = False

def s_r():
    global is_stop
    if is_stop == False:
        is_stop = True
    else:
        pass

def restart():
    global hours
    global minutes
    global seconds
    global milliseconds
    hours = 0
    minutes = 0
    seconds = 0
    milliseconds = 0
    time.set("00:00:00:00")



title = Label(window, text="Stopwatch")
title.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=3, padx=3)

time_L = Label(window, textvariable=time)
time_L.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=3, padx=3)

start = Button(window, text='Start', command=begin)
start.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=3, padx=3)

#lap = Button(window, text='Lap', command=begin)
#lap.grid(row=3, column=3, pady=3, padx=3)

stop = Button(window, text='Stop', command=s_r)
stop.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=3, padx=3)

reset = Button(window, text='Reset', command=restart)
reset.grid(row=3, column=3, pady=3, padx=3)


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about how you can reduce the latency, because that depends on the time taken for your code to perform the calculations and finally update the `time_L` label with the values. But as far as the problem with the buttons go, you can try these changes, this will enable and disable the buttons accordingly and prevent multiple clicks.

```py
def begin():
    global is_stop
    if is_stop == False:
        stop.config(state='normal')
        start.config(state='disabled')
        plus_sec()
        window.after(10, begin)
        window.update()
    else:
        pass
        is_stop = False

def s_r():
    global is_stop
    if is_stop == False:
        is_stop = True
        start.config(state='normal')
        stop.config(state='disabled')
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't aware that tkinter buttons have states! I learned something new! Thank you!